# Is there a way to dynamically selectInput and have its respectivelly textInput arranged like flowLayout?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

[image: Desired Result]

In the following code the textInput does not stay inside the dashboardSidebar. I would like to have it structured like in 3 columns and the number of rows would depend on the number of items selected using the selectInput.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- dashboardPage(
skin = "black",
title = "Dashboard",
dashboardHeader(
    title = "Dashboard",
    titleWidth = 451
),
dashboardSidebar(
    width = 451,
    sidebarMenu(
        fileInput('file1', 'Select File', accept=c('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values,text/plain','.csv'), width = 450),
        textInput("avg_info", "Population Info", placeholder = "Enter values separated by a comma", width = 450),
        br(),
        actionButton("Btn_run", "Run"),
        hr(),
        uiOutput("sel_inp"),
        uiOutput("text_sel"),
        br(),
        uiOutput("ui1"),
        br()
    )
),
dashboardBody()
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
# Track the number of input boxes to render
observeEvent(input$Btn_run, {
    output$sel_inp <- renderUI({
        selectInput("COLUMN", "Selection", choices = paste0("Item",1:15), multiple = TRUE, width = 450)
    })
    output$text_sel <- renderUI({
        trait_names <- input$COLUMN
        n <- length(trait_names)
        if (n > 0) {
            interaction <- lapply(seq_len(n), function(i) {
                textInput(inputId = trait_names[i],
                          label = trait_names[i],
                          width = 140)
            })
            do.call(flowLayout, interaction) # tagList
        }
    })
})
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is there a way to do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best solution, but it gave me the expected layout result.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(
    pageWithSidebar(
        headerPanel("Add Features"),
        sidebarPanel(width=4,
                     fluidRow(column(12,
                                     fileInput('file1', 'Select File', accept=c('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values,text/plain','.csv'), width = 450),
                                     textInput("avg_info", "Population Info", placeholder = "Enter values separated by a comma", width = 450),
                                     br(),
                                     actionButton("Btn_run", "Run"),
                                     hr(),
                                     uiOutput("sel_inp"),)), # END fluidRow
                     fluidRow(
                         column(2, uiOutput("text_sel1")),
                         column(2, uiOutput("text_sel2")),
                         column(2, uiOutput("text_sel3")),
                         column(2, uiOutput("text_sel4"))
                     ) # END fluidRow
        ), # END sidebarPanel
        mainPanel()
    )
)


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    # Track the number of input boxes to render
    observeEvent(input$Btn_run, {
        output$sel_inp <- renderUI({
            selectInput("COLUMN", "Selection", choices = paste0("Item",1:15), multiple = TRUE, width = 450)
        })
        output$text_sel1 <- renderUI({
            trait_names <- input$COLUMN
            if (length(trait_names) > 0) {
                interaction1 <- lapply(seq(1,length(trait_names), by = 3), function(i) {
                    textInput(inputId = trait_names[i], label = trait_names[i], width = 140)
                })
                do.call(tagList, interaction1)
            }
        })
        output$text_sel2 <- renderUI({
            trait_names <- input$COLUMN
            if (length(trait_names) > 1) {
                interaction2 <- lapply(seq(2,length(trait_names), by = 3), function(i) {
                    textInput(inputId = trait_names[i], label = trait_names[i], width = 140)
                })
                do.call(tagList, interaction2)
            }
        })
        output$text_sel3 <- renderUI({
            trait_names <- input$COLUMN
            if (length(trait_names) > 2) {
                interaction3 <- lapply(seq(3,length(trait_names), by = 3), function(i) {
                    textInput(inputId = trait_names[i], label = trait_names[i], width = 140)
                })
                do.call(tagList, interaction3)
            }
        })
        output$text_sel4 <- renderUI({
            trait_names <- input$COLUMN
            if (length(trait_names) > 3) {
                interaction4 <- lapply(seq(4,length(trait_names), by = 3), function(i) {
                    textInput(inputId = trait_names[i], label = trait_names[i], width = 140)
                })
                do.call(tagList, interaction4)
            }
        })
    })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```